# How do I find and replace something AFTER a specific term in a terminal output

Tags: grep, search, json, replace

I need to run `blkid` and copy a specific `UUID` after a specific known partition name.

Then, I need to paste this into an exists config file, replacing a `UUID` that it's already there (`parent_device_uuid`). Example config below.

Can anyone please demonstrate how to do this, in terms a beginner would understand?

```json
{
  "backup_device_uuid" : "cdb09919-39d4-4a17-9fc4-6daa1d38f1e1",
  "parent_device_uuid" : "IOe7Qc-fjAK-2ydl-OMk4-SvVu-1P6Y-PJSHzV",
  "do_first_run" : "false",
  "btrfs_mode" : "false",
  "include_btrfs_home_for_backup" : "false",
  "include_btrfs_home_for_restore" : "false",
  "stop_cron_emails" : "true",
  "btrfs_use_qgroup" : "true",
  "schedule_monthly" : "true",
  "schedule_weekly" : "true",
  "schedule_daily" : "true",
  "schedule_hourly" : "true",
  "schedule_boot" : "true",
  "count_monthly" : "1",
  "count_weekly" : "2",
  "count_daily" : "3",
  "count_hourly" : "3",
  "count_boot" : "1",
  "snapshot_size" : "15837901165",
  "snapshot_count" : "292512",
  "date_format" : "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
  "exclude" : [
    "/home/test/**",
    "/home/test2/**",
    "/root/**"
  ],
  "exclude-apps" : []
}
```

Comment: Is that your full json file? Or do you have more content?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon thats the full file I'm working on at the moment but there may be different ones in the future so I'd like a sortof universal solution if possible

Comment: Well, regarding various of your comments, you said you need to find the UUID based on NAME, so in your question you should have specified that. You also said *"im also really confused about which json im supposed to use"*, well, the *json file* here is your config file (and you did not provide what is the path fo the file you are talking about, for that reason I used `youroriginaljson.json` in my answer). You said you are beginner but we don't know how much you know, I supposed you know about what is a  `json` file as well as you had idea about basic shell scripting.

Comment: as far as i know a json file is a test file with json at the end. and this is the first bash script ive ever tried to write. didnt even know what a bash script was until someone told me to use it if i wanted to automatically install a bunch of apps and configure them the same on a bunch of computers.

but thats a long story so i think its pretty well summarazed as 'begginer'. i am literally just beggining. hence the question. if i knew this stuff why would i ask?

Comment: I've re-opened this question as the duplicate was removed for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are using `json` files you can make use of the command `jq`.

For getting **only** the `UUID` of some partition you can use the following:

**Using blkid with label name**

```bash
blkid -s UUID -o value -t 'LABEL=your_label_name'

#If you got: 'command not found' then you can use:
sudo blkid -s UUID -o value -t 'LABEL=your_label_name'
#or
/sbin/blkid -s UUID -o value -t 'LABEL=your_label_name'
```

Where `your_label_name` is the NAME of the device you want.

From `blkid --help`:

1. `-s` show specified tag (in this case the UUID)
2. `-o` is the output format (in this case we want the value of UUID tag)

**Using lsblk (this not uses label name)**

```bash
lsblk /dev/nvme0n1p1 -o UUID -n
```

From `lsblk --help`:

1. `-o` output columns (in this case we want only the UUID column)
2. `-n` don't print headings

#### Solution

Finally using `jq` you can replace `parent_device_uuid` with the UUID you got by using one of the commands above:

```bash
jq --arg puuid "$(blkid -s UUID -o value -t 'LABEL=your_label_name')"  '.parent_device_uuid = $puuid' < configfile > tmpconfig
mv tmpconfig configfile
```

Or if you don't have permissions when using `mv` (for moving,renaming the file) then use:

```bash
sudo mv tmpconfig configfile
```

About **configfile**, this is the file which has this content:

```json
{
  "backup_device_uuid" : "cdb09919-39d4-4a17-9fc4-6daa1d38f1e1",
  "parent_device_uuid" : "IOe7Qc-fjAK-2ydl-OMk4-SvVu-1P6Y-PJSHzV",
  "do_first_run" : "false",
  "btrfs_mode" : "false",
  "include_btrfs_home_for_backup" : "false",
  "include_btrfs_home_for_restore" : "false",
  "stop_cron_emails" : "true",
  "btrfs_use_qgroup" : "true",
  "schedule_monthly" : "true",
  "schedule_weekly" : "true",
  "schedule_daily" : "true",
  "schedule_hourly" : "true",
  "schedule_boot" : "true",
  "count_monthly" : "1",
  "count_weekly" : "2",
  "count_daily" : "3",
  "count_hourly" : "3",
  "count_boot" : "1",
  "snapshot_size" : "15837901165",
  "snapshot_count" : "292512",
  "date_format" : "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
  "exclude" : [
    "/home/test/**",
    "/home/test2/**",
    "/root/**"
  ],
  "exclude-apps" : []
}
```

About `jq` the arguments: `--arg puuid "$(blkid -s UUID -o value -t 'LABEL=your_label_name')"` are used to assign the `UUID` of your device to the variable `puuid`. And `'.parent_device_uuid = $puuid'` changes `"parent_device_uuid" : "IOe7Qc-fjAK-2ydl-OMk4-SvVu-1P6Y-PJSHzV" to what` puuid` has (which is the UUID of the device)

Comment: A more generic `jq` expression for inserting any named variable from any `--arg` option: `jq --arg parent_device_uuid "...somestring..." '. += $ARGS.named' file`

Comment: @Kusalananda oh, thanks your tip! That's much better :D

Comment: thanks, the blkid command worked but the problem is i need to find the UUID based on NAME, not /dev/ehatever.

im also really confused about which json im supposed to use....why are there two different files now, im only trying to change info in one

Comment: @Kusalananda i have absolutely zero idea what any of that means, how on earth could a beginner make sense of that

Comment: @Capybara_Overdose The tool `jq` is used to process `json` files. There are many tutorials about how to use `jq`. Also you can get help by using `man jq` or `jq --help`. The Kusalananda's comment is similar to what I provided but better (unless for me)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon i spent literally a whole two days trying to google tutorials to help me with this, there is LITERALLY NOTHING out there that a begginer can understand, everyone in Linux talks and write like you people here, as if you assume every has a CS degree by defualt and just already knows how to speak in code and answer their own question in the first place.

I cant find anything on "jq" that makes any more sense, its not different. Complete nerdspeak. I jsut want to get this to work, not spend months learning unnecessary things i have no need of